# Bring your own theme to PHP 8

Tags: php, theme-development

My self-created theme no longer works under PHP 8. I would like to change it so that it continues to work. Currently only the navigation is displayed.

I have deactivated all plugins.

I have tried to solve this via [the help page](https://anchor.host/common-php-v8-1-compatibility-fixes-for-wordpress/), but I can't find the error(s).

I have provided the theme as [a ZIP](https://www.johanneskroening.de/theme.zip).

I would be grateful for any help.

The page I need help with: https://www.johanneskroening.de/

Comment: I see that you found the answer. But your error.log file should be the first place you look. (This is for future lurkers.) Turning on DEBUG in the wp-config.php file will also help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the error.

In the header.php an undefined constant was tried to be accessed. So instead of the following wrong code:

```
<?php if ($pagetitle == pagetitle_1){

  $pt1 = "pagetitle_1";

  $main = "main_1";

} else {

  $pt1 = "";

}

?>
```

I had to add the quotation marks to pagetitle:

```
<?php if ($pagetitle == "pagetitle_1"){

  $pt1 = "pagetitle_1";

  $main = "main_1";

} else {

  $pt1 = "";

}

?>
```